# How find subfolders in the folder, then move the subfolders to another folder by using batch command

Tags: batch-file

Example:

```
Folder tree: 

    C:\
    |
    |---lion
    |     |---one
    |     |---two
    |     |---three
    |
    |---bear
```

I need move subfolders (one, two, three, etc.) in the folder "bear".

I know how to find and move specific file types, but how to find and move the folders don't know:

```
for /R "c:\one" %%f in (*.jpg) do move /Y "%%f" "c:\two"
```

Comment: Look into `forfiles` if your using windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Try this (fixed):

```
for /d /r "C:\lion" %%a in (*) do md "C:\bear\%%~nxa" &robocopy /e /move "%%~fa" "C:\bear\%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\lion"
for /d %%a in (*) do move "%%a" "c:\bear"
popd
```